# ASP.NET Core how can I link the front end to the back end?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, frontend, backend

Ok so the purpose of my project is to have files uploaded to a site. I have done that through relative path mapping. Now I have added a navigation menu, 1 for the admin and 1 for the user. I want to have a file uploaded (by the admin) to a certain category (as of now, they are displayed in a single category using listing) so that the user will have to click that certain category in order to see that specific file. How do I do that?
This is my razor page :

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        <!-- In order to post files to server we should use form with post method, also need to add multipart/form-data encoding.
               Otherwise the files will not sent to the server. -->

        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="catform">
            <input asp-for="Files" type="file" name="files" multiple />
            <button type="submit">Upload</button>

        </form>




        <p>Alegeti categoria de personal pentru care doriti sa uploadati</p>


        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">


                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Alegeti categoria

                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Incepatori</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Avansati</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Admini</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                </ul>
                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </nav>
    }
    @if (User.IsInRole("User"))
    {
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Incepatori</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Avansati</a>
                    </li>
                    

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Admini</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </nav>
    } 






public IActionResult Index1()
        {
            // Get files from the server
            var model = new FilesViewModel();
            foreach (var item in Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "upload")))
            {
                model.Files.Add(
                    new FileDetails { Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item), Path = item });
            }
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index1(IFormFile[] files)
        {
            // Iterate each files
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                // Get the file name from the browser
                var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                // Get file path to be uploaded
                var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "upload", fileName);
                

                




                // Check If file with same name exists and delete it
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
                }

                // Create a new local file and copy contents of uploaded file
                using (var localFile = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(filePath)) 
                    using (var uploadedFile = file.OpenReadStream())

                    {
                       



                        uploadedFile.CopyTo(localFile);








                    }
        
            }
            ViewBag.Message = "Files are successfully uploaded";

            // Get files from the server
            var model = new FilesViewModel();
            foreach (var item in Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "upload")))
            {
                model.Files.Add(
                    new FileDetails { Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item), Path = item });
                
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: the code below is the upload code from the cotroller

Comment: Did you mean that you have a folder in your project which stores all the files uploaded by admin, and you wanna users navigate to a specific page and then they can see list of file name? Just file name? Or need to download?

Comment: yes, you are correct!

Comment: You can try my code below and it really worked in my side : ) Or any further issue?

Comment: In my code I have something similar too for listing, but I want to have them listed by categories, so for example whenever I upload something I want to have the option to have it uploaded to a category, and for the user part, whenever he clicks (it will be a nav bar) on a category, he will only have displayed the items from that certain category...

Comment: Hi, based on the code snippet, I found that the menus in the nav bar seems to be limited and fixed, they all have their own action route in the controller. So is it possible to point to the specific folder in the controller for list files? Or the issue you are faced is find a solution to make admin choose a specific folder when uploading file?

Comment: I mean, when user click `Avansati` then it will reach the action named `Avansati` , and in that method you can use `Directory.GetFiles` to get files stored in the folder `Avansati`.

Answer (score 1):

This 2 methods in my controller which are used to list and download files in wwwroot/upload folder in my project.

```
public IActionResult files() {
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "upload/"));
            List<MyFile> files = new List<MyFile>();
            foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
            {
                files.Add(new MyFile { filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath) });
            }
            return View(files);
        }

        public IActionResult DownloadFile(string fileName)
        {
            string path = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "upload/") + fileName;
            byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            return File(bytes, "text/plain", fileName);
        }
```

And this is my view page code:

```
@model List<WebApplication2.Models.MyFile>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>File Name</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (MyFile file in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            @*<td>@file.filename</td>*@
            <td>@Html.ActionLink(@file.filename, "DownloadFile", new { fileName = file.filename })</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

[image]